# What is the relationship between the javascript API and the COM API of internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

We can manipulate the content of the current web page either by the javascript in the page itself or by calling the COM from an external process,like the webdriver for IE.  What is the relationship between the two sets of APIs? Is one built upon the other or are they independent? What can be done by the COM API while cannot by the in-page javascript and vice versa ?

Comment: JavaScript API being what? The term is way too lose in the Selenium/WebDriver sense. `In page javascript` means what?

Comment: In-page means the javascript code in the <script > tag in the html page.

Comment: How does that relate to Selenium? Selenium isn't adding `script` tags for what it needs to do.

Comment: Yes,Selenium-webdriver use COM API for IE,not javascript .

Comment: Yes, it's one of the only stable ways Selenium can interact with IE. Chrome/Firefox have different ways and different API's that have been opened to allow much cleaner ways of interacting with it. So what's the issue?

Comment: I want to know whether the IE implementation of the javascript DOM functions also call the COM API under the hood , just as the IE webdriver, or not.

Comment: Why the Chrome or Firefox way is much cleaner ?